# Flask - Access another website through server

Tags: python, flask, python-requests

I have a flask server, which is connected via `vpn` to another local machine. To have access to the local machine, I reroute it through:

```
@app.route('/portal/<page>')
def portal(page):
    return requests.get('http://192.168.0.69/'+page).content
```

This allows me to open every page on the local machine. But there are some `php` forms on the page that I cant figure out how to post to.

I tried:

```
@app.route('/portal/<page>', methods=['POST','GET'])
def portal(page):
    if request.form:
        return requests.post('http://192.168.0.69/'+page, data = request.form).content
    else:
        return requests.get('http://192.168.0.69/'+page).content
```

But this only ends up refreshing the page. Nothing happens.

Comment: First, if you have Debugging enabled in Flask, you will get some debug messages when sending the POST request. To enable debugging, add `app.config['DEBUG']` at the top of your code. Then, show the debug messages here.

Answer (score 0):

Isn't it possible to run proxi on LOWER OSI level? If yes, it would be much easier to use row sockets (`from socket import socket`)